# Image appearing lower in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My button looks fine in all browsers(Firefox, Safari, Chrome) except IE 10 (I tested on two different computers with windows 8.1). The image appears to be a bit lower in IE while other browsers have it right in the middle.

**IE:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
#checkout {
    background-image: url(../img/checkout.jpg);
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    float: right;
    width: 184px;
    height: 29px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type='submit' id='checkout' class='jcart-button' value='' />
```

**I have tried using:**

```
line-height: 29px;
```

Also, I noticed it works fine when I use `input type='image'` but the problem with that is, I need the ability to have a different image on hover. `onMouseClick` does the trick but doesn't work without javascript. I need something that works without javascript as well.

**Edit:**

Removed all my css except the `#checkout` part but I am still encountering the problem. So I think it is a problem with the `#checkout` css or the HTML part.

**demo:** [link](http://asiraj.com)

Comment: It might be a margins and/or padding thing.

Comment: demo: [link](http://asiraj.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer after hours of debugging :)

All I had to do was remove the border from the image and use:

```
border: none;
```

I hope that helps others!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because all browsers have quite different user agent settings for input element.

Those differences are found in margins, padding, border and god knows what else.
Open DevTools (F12) and you can see all the rules involved with the `input` and `input[type="submit"]` element.

To be absolutely cross-browser-sure you have to set all those rules manually for `#checkout` in the CSS.

---

### **UPDATE:**

Could also be that you didn't set the width and height of the button correct.
The way you have it now it's actually not perfectly in the middle. As you can also see in your screenshots, the left/top of the button has a white edge, the right/bottom doesn't.

If I change it to `width:186px;` and `height:31px;`, it is perfect.
(With any luck that also fixes your problem in Win8.1/IE10, or at least makes it less obvious)

Comment: this is awkward.. for me they are exactly the same (I'm using IE11 on Win7 though)

Comment: Yes, I believe it might be with Windows 8.1. I tested with 2 different computers. It seems to work fine on a Windows 7 computer I test on

Comment: @iheartbreakz - since you're so meticulous about that button; the way you have it now it's actually not perfectly in the middle. As you can also see in your screenshots, the left/top of the button has a white edge, the right/bottom doesn't. If if change it to `width:186px;` and `height:31px;`, it is perfect. (With any luck that also fixes your problem in Win8.1/IE10, or at least makes it less obvious)